# How do i check if a struct inside another struct is empty?

Tags: c, struct

Here are my two structs:

```
typedef struct simple_command_t {
    char * in, *out, *err;
    char **tokens;
    int builtin;
} simple_command;

typedef struct command_t {
    struct command_t *cmd1, *cmd2;
    simple_command* scmd;
    char oper[2];
} command;
```

And here is the code I'm using:

```
int main() {
    command *check1;

    if ((check1 -> scmd -> tokens) == NULL){
        printf("tokens are null");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Since I've read that you can't check if a struct is `NULL` I've tried checking the members inside of the empty struct instead. Unfortunately everything I've tried so far has been giving me segfaults.  What's the problem?

Comment: Remember that automatic (=local) variables are not initialized. You have to set their members null explicitly. This means you cannot know whether `(check1 -> scmd -> tokens) == NULL)` is true or not. In the code you show `scmd ` wouldn't be initialized to anything so your program is either producing nonsense (on small systems) or crashing right awyay (on modern normal computers). One easy way to zero your variables (including structures) is to define them with external linkage (outside any function) or static (inside a function).

Comment: What's the broader goal you're trying to achieve?

Comment: How do i check if someone hasn't initialized it then? This code is assuming that someone has initialized check1 and initialized everything else but didn't set scmd to anything. So i need to see if the person didn't initialize scmd.

Comment: `command *check1;` is not initialized and pointing anywhere in the memory, when you accessing this address with `check1 -> scmd` it's have almost 100% chance of seg fault!
You must set uninitialized pointer with a NULL value and doing NULL test before access.

Comment: if someone initializes check1 but doesn't initialize scmd. Whats the best way to check if it's not initialized? surely i can't just set it to null to check if its null.

Comment: "someone" is indeed a programmer that has to know how C works in order to use your struct. Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer is just as wrong as dividing by zero. If you do it, it is one of the innumerable undefined behaviours of the language, and anything can happen.

Comment: You can't tell if `scmd` has been initialized or not. It's up to that mysterious "someone" that created the structure to properly initialize the entire structure, which may mean setting `scmd` to `NULL` if not needed.

Comment: @Cidian: Saying that dereferencing an uninitialized pointer has an "almost 100% chance" of causing a seg fault is overly optimistic. The pointer value is garbage. That garbage might very well be a valid pointer value that was previously stored in the same location.

Comment: @keith-thompson In that case it's a dangling pointer obtained from  a previously valid pointer that can still be used after malloc and free calls. With the example of this question that i use to obtain sample core dump i never get a valid pointer value but it's just random.

Comment: @Cidian: It's not *random*, it's *arbitrary*. Typically the value will be whatever bit pattern was in that chunk of memory before it was allocated to hold your pointer object. Whether that value happens to appear to be  "valid" depends on more factors than I care to think about. On a system without memory protection where the entire address space is accessible (I've used such systems, but not lately), dereferencing a garbage pointer is very likely to give you what appears to be valid data.

Comment: @KeithThompson The probability to have an address which is not part of the program's address space will be much closer to 100% than 99% on a computer with a 64 bit architecture. Probably even on a 32 bit machine if your program didn't allocate much memory. [Well, unless something belonging to the program was lingering on the stack. Not the case in this code]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as an "empty" struct. (The phrase "empty struct" would make sense if C permitted structs with no members, but it doesn't, and that's not what you're referring to anyway.)

I think what you're trying to do is check whether the struct has been *initialized*, either via an initializer or an assignment. There is no way to do that.

Here's a simpler example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
    int *ptr;
    /* code that may or may not initialize ptr */
    if (<ptr has been initialized>) {
        printf("ptr = %p, *ptr = %d\n", (void*)ptr, *ptr);
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "ptr is uninitialized\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

There is no way to write the condition `<ptr has been initialized>`. Since `ptr` is not a `static` object, its initial value is not necessarily a null pointer or any other particular value; it is indeterminate garbage. It could, just by coincidence, happen to contain a valid address; there is no way to distinguish between that possibility and an actual valid value that was stored in `ptr` deliberately.

The only reliable way to determine whether `ptr` has been initialized or not is to initialize it:

```
int *ptr = NULL;
```

The same reasoning applies to your example.  You define a pointer object:

```
command *check1;
```

It's defined in side a function, it's not `static`, so its initial value is indeterminate garbage. Just reading the value of the pointer:

```
if (check1 == NULL) ...
```

has undefined behavior; even if it didn't, the result of the comparison wouldn't tell you anything useful. You must carefully write your code so that you never attempt to use the value of `check1` before assigning a known value to it. The easiest way to do that is simply to initialize it:

```
command *check1 = NULL;
```

If you initialize it to `NULL` it doesn't point to anything; there is no structure object to test.  You can create a structure and assign its address to `check1`:

```
check1 = malloc(sizeof *check1);
```

Now `check1` has a valid value (which could still be a null pointer of `malloc` failed; always check for that). If `malloc` succeeded, `check1` points to a struct object whose value itself is indeterminate garbage. The same considerations that applied to `check1` itself now apply to the struct object `*check1`, and to each of its members.

One common approach is to define a function that creates a struct object and properly initializes all its members.